# Haml code conversion from Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, indentation

I have this code mentioned below and I am trying to make it work on a RoR application under haml extension. However I am getting unexpected keyword end. I read over the net and stackoverflow and found out that end is not required in HAML. However when I remove it I get an error saying that end keyword is expected. Could you please check and tip me what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
<div id="comments">
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
    <div class ="comment">
    <%= simple_format comment.content %>
</div>
<%end%>
</div>
```

What I did so far is:

```
%h1 Comments
 .comments
 - @comments.each do |comment|
 .comment
 = simple_format comment.content
```

Any clues? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that haml is based on 2 space indentations.  The correct haml version of your html is

```
#comments
  - @comments.each do |comment|
    .comment
      = simple_format comment.content
```

Comment: @Bookies: please mark this answer as the solution and upvote it, if you like